# How to simulate an app purchase in Windows 8 Store App development?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to simulate an app purchase for my unit test using the following code:

```
currentApp.requestAppPurchaseAsync(false);
```

It does return the S_OK code indicating a successful purchase but my unit test is failing because `licenseInformation.isTrial` is coming back as true.

I am under the impression that it should change the isTrial to false as I just purchased it.

Thoughts??

Comment: You never mentioned "and I use CurrentAppSimulator to run the test".  Do you?

Comment: I am using CurrentAppSimulator

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
await currentApp.requestAppPurchaseAsync(false);
```

My guess is that your unit test is continuing before the asynchronous method completes and the license is actually purchased.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using html/js project to build my store app. What is the equivalent command in js?